# Add string "Absence recorded at" from the mod history page into Traducir/Transifex

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, localization, traducir, moderation-history

This is how the SOru moderator history page (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin) looks:

> [image]

The string:

> Absence recorded at

Could you add this string into Traducir/Transifex, so we will be able to translate it?

Currently it's "Absence was recorder at:"

> [image]

Comment: Technically it reads "Absence was recorded at:" now, but the issue is still present. I'll forward this to the relevant dev team.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fixed now! Thanks for the report - I also fixed it up so that screen reader translations will make more sense too.

Comment: It seems that "Absence reason:" should not be visible if not specified.

Comment: And date should be printed in site specific format, not as US only `mm/dd/yyyy AM`

Comment: Oops - you're totally right, not sure why I assumed that mods *had* to specify a reason. Thanks for letting me know - getting a fix for both of those issues ready to go now, should be out within the next couple of days.