# Moderator absence reason part should not be visible if there's no reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderation-history

Recently [fixed issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329273/339911) with translation on moderator dashboard introduced a new behavior. Now the "Absence reason:" title is always visible even in case when there's no reason filled by inactive moderator. Before that issue was fixed, this string used to be hidden when a moderator had not entered a reason for absence, but is now shown always:

[image: "Absence reason:"]

[image: same in Russian]

Could this please be fixed, i.e., don't show "Absence reason:" line when the absence reason is absent?

Comment: Absence of data is also data... Completely hiding a line is pretty bad UX.

Comment: Indicating there was no reason specified by the moderator is desirable, IMO. I don't like the idea of just completely not showing the text that explains the purpose of the field and that indicates it's blank. Not showing the field at all has a substantially higher chance of hiding bugs and is generally against SE's UX philosophy. If you and others are uncomfortable with showing a blank area for something that's *actually blank*, then, perhaps, having the system display something like "[no reason provided]", or something similar would be reasonable.

Comment: @Cerbrus hiding a non-existed data is bad UX? I don't think so. A bunch of `<not specified>` on a page is worse than empty space. No sense to overwhelm the page. Just imagine that any non-closed question here would have an extra `[non-closed]` or `[open]`! It's a hiding a data as well as you said.

Comment: That's not the same. A moderator might as well be absent without a provided reason, then you'd still have that title there. Besides, we're talking about some moderator dashboard there. It doesn't have to be "fancy", it should contain as much information as is available.

Comment: Oh, and considering we're on SE meta here, you might want to update your screenshot to English. As it is right now, the screenshot has no context, nor useful content...

Comment: @Cerbrus That's kind of hard to do if the only site(s) you moderate are international sites, though. Also, the text used to be hidden before the linked issue was fixed, and showing it today is not as per the design; are you suggesting that the design be changed to accommodate the current behavior?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog he could use a browser plugin to translate the page. And yes, if the design doesn't match, then that should be updated.

Comment: @Sonic are you sure it was hidden because there was no absence reason? Might also be because there was no translation to the string.

Comment: @Cerbrus The machine translation might not match the English string shown to moderators of non-international sites, making it further confusing for them.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack That could be the case. I think it's best if a mod of a non-international site could tell us what they used to see.

Comment: @ShadowW I never heard or faced with such things on SE that absence of translation in Transifex may leads to eliminate the original string from the page content. As far as I know how it works on SE it's not possible to achieve this, and this makes no sense to do. In that case we will loose the ability to translate at all, if source string will be hidden from the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now. No extra row displayed if the reason is absent.

Thank you, unknown developer.